# How to get data from api using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, express, axios

Postman gets the data correctly but axios get the wrong data, it receives the "Not found" but there is a record in DB.

react hook:

```
import axios from "axios";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export default function useRoom(roomName) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [room, setRoom] = useState({})
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      body: {
        "roomName": "test1"
      },
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "http://localhost:4444/room",
    }).then(res => {
      setRoom(res.data)
      console.log(res)
      setLoading(false)
    }).catch(e => {
      setError(e.toString())
      setLoading(true)
    })
  }, [roomName])

  return {
    error,
    room,
    loading
  }
}
```

NODE JS:

```
app.post('/room', (req, res) => {
  Room.findOne({roomName: req.body.roomName}, async (err, doc) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!doc) res.send("No Room Found");
    else {
      res.send(doc);
    }
  })
})
```

Postman receives the data but the axios doesn't

[image: postman works correctly]

I have the data in my db
[image: mongo atlas]

What I get in the browser console:

[image]

How I use my hook:
[image]

If someone knows how to solve this issue please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but maybe you should use 'data' instead of 'body' :

```
axios({
  method: "POST",
  data: { // <--- HERE 
    "roomName": "test1"
  },
  withCredentials: true,
  url: "http://localhost:4444/room",
})
```

Comment: yea, it works, thanks! Will approve in 8 mins